# EnumHelper returns description instead Enum value

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, enums

I use an `EnumHelper` method and try to get both description and `enum` value (Id) as shown below:

***EnumHelper:***

```
public static class MyEnumHelper
{
    public static string GetDescription<T>(this T enumerationValue)
        where T : struct
    {
        System.Type type = enumerationValue.GetType();
        if (!type.IsEnum)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Must be Enum type", "enumerationValue");
        }
        //for the enum
        MemberInfo[] memberInfo = type.GetMember(enumerationValue.ToString());
        if (memberInfo != null && memberInfo.Length > 0)
        {
            object[] attrs = memberInfo[0]
                .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);

            if (attrs != null && attrs.Length > 0)
            {
                return ((DescriptionAttribute)attrs[0]).Description;
            }
        }
        return enumerationValue.ToString();
    }
}
```

***Enum:***

```
public enum StatusEnum
{
    [Description("Deleted")]
    Deleted= 0,

    [Description("Active")]
    Active= 1,

    [Description("Passive")]
    Passive= 2
}
```

***Entity:***

```
public class DemoEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public StatusEnum StatusId { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public string StatusName
    {
        get { return MyEnumHelper.GetDescription(StatusId); }
    }
}
```

***Controller:***

```
DemoEntity entity = DemoEntity();
entity.StatusId = StatusEnum.Passive; 
// !!! This returns "Passive" instead of its value 2. How can I get its value?
```

However, when trying to assign `Id` value of an `enum` by using strongly type feature of the `enum` as shown above, I still get its description instead of `Id`. Any idea about where the problem is?

Comment: I think that's the point of the Description, to display the value in a stringed format. The number is still there in the back. If you really want to see the number, you could convert it to an integer.

Comment: ````(int)StatusEnum.Passive```` should get you the integer value.

Comment: @JohnPete. Voted up. In this case, there is no problem regarding to this approach in Entity and Enum definitions, and I just need to convert enum values to int when I need its value. Is that true? Or do you suggest another approach that is better than this?

Comment: @the_lotus. In this case, there is no problem regarding to this approach in Entity and Enum definitions, and I just need to convert enum values to int when I need its value. Is that true? Or do you suggest another approach that is better than this?

Comment: It's already an int.. just a named int. You aren't "converting it per se

Comment: It will always be an int, I don't think you need any conversion. You will see it as a string when ever you want to display the value only.

Comment: @the_lotus Ok, but what about my question above regarding to this approach?

Comment: Why do you think you need "to convert enums to ints"?

Comment: @hexadecimal to be honest, I don't see any problems in this whole thing. It's all working like it's supposed to. Enum are still numbers even if they have descriptions unless you display them (debug, toString, …). If you save your enum in the database, it'll be a number.

Comment: @the_lotus Hmmm, very important point that made me confused after saving the enum to database. Additionally, I also think display concern and now with your nice explanations, I understand that I can save enum values to database directly without any conversiton (int) and when I need to display, I can use its Description. Is that true? Many thnaks again.

Comment: @CaiusJard Sorry, I think there is no need to make a conversion when saving enum values to database. I just realized it after the_lotus's last comment. I think you also pointed this issue. In that case, I think it is useless to make a conversion while saving it to database, is that true?

Comment: It depends how you have the enums in the database; we actually save the string verson in the DB and have the ORM map the string value back to the enum for use in code. It's much nicer to see DB tables that arent rammed full of magic numbers, that require another Join to decode them into a presentable value eg `SELECT * FROM order WHERE status = 'Active'` rather than `SELECT * FROM order o inner join orderstatu os on o.status = os.statusid WHERE os.StatusName = 'Active'`.. but to answer your question; sure any method that takes an int can have an enum passed in if you cast the enum to an int

Comment: @CaiusJard I just checked the data type of the StatusId on database and see that it is int type that I wanted. But in the entity, I typed it as StatusEnum. I am not sure if there is a confusion regarding to this? It is ok StatusEnum when keeping its value StatusId as int on the database? I just want to be clarified if there is something wrong in my entity and enum definitions.

Comment: If it's StatusId in the DB it'll definitely make your life easier to have an `int StatusId` in your class (for the ORM to use)` but in your code, certainly I would recommend you cast the `int` to a `StatusEnum` (or whatever you called your `enum Status...`) and then use StatusENum through your code. You can of course link the two things together in the properties so that they use the same backing value. Consider taking the code in my post and declaring that the Status (enum) property is the one that is NotMapped, and make the StatusId property a get/set for the ORM to use

Comment: Have a read of something like this: https://medium.com/agilix/entity-framework-core-enums-ee0f8f4063f2 or this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions - it'll tell you how to have a Status enum on your C# object but have it stored in the DB as StatusId, and have EF Core (if you're using it - i've assumed from the aspnetcore tag) do the conversion so that an int is stored in the DB but a Enum is used in code. Do consider the option of storing the *string* in the db instead, as it makes looking at table data much nicer

Comment: @CaiusJard Thanks a lot, I will look at both of these articles.

Comment: @CaiusJard Regarding to your previous comment, I think it is better to include `public int StatusId` property (in your answer) to the entity classes where enum values are used. Is that true?

Comment: @CaiusJard Any comment for my last question?

Comment: I don't personally see the need for it; providing things means that people tend to use them, and poorer quality code results when ints  are used instead of enum. For example, what does this line of code mean: `if(activity.Phase == 2 || (activity.Phase == 3 && (activity.ProtectionModes & 1 == 1)))` ? Yep.. it means nothing unless you know what those numbers are. Compare `if(activity.Phase == Phase.Starting || (activity.Phase == Phase.Running && (activity.ProtectionModes & Modes.CanAutoShutdown == Modes.CanAutoShutDown)))` - you can instantly know the conditions when this `if` will run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have perhaps done this:

```
public enum Status
{
    Deleted= 0,
    Active= 1,
    Passive= 2
}

public class DemoEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public Status Status { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public string StatusName
    {
        get { return this.Status.ToString("g"); }
    }

    [NotMapped]
    public int StatusId
    {
        get { return (int)this.Status; }
    }
}
```

- Don't suffix "Enum" onto your enums - you don't do it for classes (DemoEntityClass?) and Intellisense draws a clear distinction between a class and an enum (for example). Microsoft don't do it (StringSplitOptions, not StringSplitOptionsEnum)
- If your description attributes are the same as your enum name values (as yours are), ToString("g") is a simpler, baked in way of turning the enum name into a string
- Enums are named ints; ints can be cast back and forth to enums willingly. If you try to cast an int to an enum and it is not a member of the enum, it just carries on behaving as the same int value (`((Status)3).ToString()` returns "3");

Consider the library [Enums.Net](https://github.com/TylerBrinkley/Enums.NET) if you're getting heavy into work with enums

Comment: Thanks, but throws **_'Status' is a type, which is not valid in the given context_** error.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't miss a `this` ? My code works fine, look: https://dotnetfiddle.net/p6gOA0

Comment: Sorry, just a mistake. Many thanks for your helps, voted up.

Answer (score 1):

just cast your enum to int if you need the value

```
entity.Id = (int)StatusEnum.Passive;
```

Comment: as JohnPete22 had answered before you, I select his answer as the first answer. But I also voted up your answer ;) Thanks...

Comment: @hexadecimal JohnPete made a comment; he didn't answer the question, and upvoting a comment isn't much use. CharlesP provided an answer; JohnPete should not have provided an answer in a comment, because that's not what SO comments are for (The placeholder text in the comment box even says "avoid answering questions in comments")